# AWS CodeBuild build fails on mvn package command

Tags: java, maven, aws-codebuild

I'm trying to automatically deploy a simple maven project to AWS lambda using Github, codebuild. When I build the project locally and upload the JAR file to lambda its works fine. However the issue occurs when I try to build the project using codebuild it always fails on a build stage throwing "**COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR: Error while executing command: mvn package. Reason: exit status 1**".

below is my buildspec.yml

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      java: corretto11
  build:
    commands:
      - mvn package
      - sam package
        --template-file template.yml
        --s3-bucket iit-cloud
        --output-template-file packaged-template.yml
artifacts:
  files:
    - target/HelloWorld-1.0.jar
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QdieJ.png)

Please kindly help me